# Unresolved External Symbol Occuring with Class Files

Tags: c++, direct3d

First point: I'm not a C++ expert, far from it.  I glanced at it briefly almost a year ago and have not touched again until about 2 weeks ago when I decided to teach myself DirectX in C++.  I have had my fair share of errors but have (for the most part) been able to solve them myself.  I give up on this one though.  As far as I can tell the problem resides in how I am using the .h and .cpp files of the mapCube class, so I will post those.

The errors themselves are few but infuriating:  I get a **LINK:2019** unresolved external symbol error regarding all the functions of mapCube **except** the constructors, it tells me they are referenced in the main program but claims they are not initialized.  The second error I know of has to do with the checkColl function, in that function alone VC++ 2010 decides that x, y, and z are no longer a part of the mapCube class, it is rather perplexing.

The code:
mapCube.h

```
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <dinput.h>

extern const float TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT;
extern LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;

// include the Direct3D Library files
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dinput8.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxguid.lib")

#ifndef MAPCUBE_H
#define MAPCUBE_H

class mapCube{
        struct CUSTOMVERTEX {FLOAT X, Y, Z; D3DVECTOR NORMAL; DWORD COLOR;};    //might be able to put these elsewhere
        #define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_NORMAL | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)             //they are already in main, but mapCube needs them too
public:
    LPD3DXMESH cubeMesh;
    float x,y,z;
    void setCoord(float, float, float);
    D3DXVECTOR3 getCoord(){return D3DXVECTOR3(x,y,z);};
    mapCube();
    mapCube(float, float, float);
    mapCube(float, float, float, D3DXCOLOR);
    void draw(D3DXMATRIX);
    void setColor(D3DXCOLOR);
    int checkColl(D3DXVECTOR3, D3DXVECTOR3);
};

#endif
```

mapCube.cpp

```
#include "mapCube.h"

mapCube::mapCube()
{
    x=0;
    y=0;
    z=0;
    setColor(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(128,128,128));
} 

mapCube::mapCube(float nx, float ny, float nz)
{
    x=nx;
    y=ny;
    z=nz;
    setColor(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(128,128,128));
}

mapCube::mapCube(float nx, float ny, float nz, D3DXCOLOR color)
{
    x=nx;
    y=ny;
    z=nz;
    setColor(color);
}

void mapCube::setCoord(float nx, float ny, float nz)    //this function and the next one are both called
{                                                       //when the cube is created because I'm using
        x=nx;                                               //an array of cubes instead of one-by-one
    y=ny;
    z=nz;
};

void mapCube::setColor(D3DXCOLOR color)             //basically just colors each vertex 'color'
{
    LPD3DXMESH tmpMesh=NULL;

    D3DXCreateBox(d3ddev, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH, &tmpMesh, NULL);

    tmpMesh->CloneMeshFVF( 0, CUSTOMFVF, d3ddev, &cubeMesh );

    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 tmpVertBuf=NULL;

if( SUCCEEDED(cubeMesh->GetVertexBuffer(&tmpVertBuf)))
{
    int nNumVerts = cubeMesh->GetNumVertices();
    CUSTOMVERTEX *pVertices = NULL;

    tmpVertBuf->Lock( 0, 0, (void**)&pVertices, 0 );
    {
            int i=0;
            while(i<nNumVerts)
            {
                pVertices[i].COLOR=color;
                i++;
            }
        }
    tmpVertBuf->Unlock();

    tmpVertBuf->Release();
    }
};

void mapCube::draw(D3DXMATRIX matWorld)
{
    D3DXMATRIX matTranslate;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate,x,y,z);         //translation to the cubes stored coordinates

    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matTranslate * matWorld));      //...combined with the total world transform
    cubeMesh->DrawSubset(0);
};

int checkColl(D3DXVECTOR3 vecTest, D3DXVECTOR3 vecThis)         //2nd arg bc compiler decided to forget
{                                                               //that this class has x,y,z vars
    if(vecTest.x>=vecThis.x-(TILE_WIDTH/2.0f) || vecTest.x<=vecThis.x+(TILE_WIDTH/2.0f))    //rudimentary attempt at collision checking
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(vecTest.z>=vecThis.z-(TILE_HEIGHT/2.0f) || vecTest.z<=vecThis.z+(TILE_HEIGHT/2.0f))
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Sorry if the formatting is a bit off, this is the first time I have used this interface.  The compiler reports no syntax errors or otherwise, after I change the x/z references in the last function to a passed D3D vector anyway.  Any help/criticism is welcome, whether it relates to d3d or c++.  I didn't post the main source because I do not believe the problem is there, but if asked I will post it as well.

Following the solution of that problem, I now notice this warning:
    1>Debug\mapCube.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
I removed the duplicate definitions of CUSTOMVERTEX and FVF and made them extern in the header, but am unable to resolve these problems.

Comment: Your `MAPCUBE_H` header guard should be at the top of the header file, before you include anything.

Comment: Thanks, never was much for error checking and the like so I am kinda picking it up as I go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to add mapCube.cpp to your VC++ project. Add this line to the top of mapCube.cpp:

```
#error This file is indeed being compiled
```

If that line does not generate a compiler error, then mapCube.cpp is not being compiled.

---

Try Rebuild Solution. Sometimes things get out of sync, and you just have to recompile everything from scratch.

Comment: Good and bad side to that:   Bad(in terms of solving the problem)=It printed the error  Good=I know for certain that it is being compiled and the phrasing gave me a sorely needed laugh

Comment: You did indeed add mapCube.cpp to your project as a source file (Add Source File), and didn't do something silly like `#include "mapCube.cpp"`, right?

Comment: You can also try Rebuild Solution. Sometimes things get out of sync, and you just have to recompile everything from scratch.

Comment: I only #include the header file for the class but following a rebuild I no longer receive a LINK:2019 error...now I am getting a LNK4042 **warning.**  So it does now actually run although I am curious about that warning.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @coderCobra: As for the LNK4042 warning, it could be because you're defining the same global variables in multiple modules. "Public" global variables should be declared `extern` in a header file, and defined only once in **one** source file. If you edit your question to show the recent inker warnings, then perhaps we can give you an idea of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought it is worth pointing to the bleeding obvious, but is mapCube.cpp included in your project?

Answer (score 0):

The second issue is easily solved: the `checkColl` implementation (in `mapCube.cpp`) is missing its `mapCube::` prefix. This causes the compiler to think it is a "free function", not a member function of `mapCube`.

Comment: I guess that is what I get for staring at the code all day, a noob moment...thanks though.